# How to deal with Maybe type in Haskell list comprehensions II

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with implementing a maybe type in to list manipulation!

What I need to do is:

```
ljoin [(2,"S"),(1,"J")] [(2,1),(2,2),(3,4)]
     outputs: [(2,"S",Just 1),(2,"S",Just 2),(1,"J",Nothing)]
```

What I written so far:

```
ljoin :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,Maybe c)]
ljoin xs ys = [if xs==ys then (xa, xb, Just yc) else (xa, xb, Nothing) | (xa, xb) <- xs, (ya, yc) <- ys]
```

Which produces the error:

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : ljoin
*** Expected type : Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,c)] -> [(a,b,Maybe c)]
*** Inferred type : Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b,Maybe b)]
```

Am I on the right track doing it this way and just need to keep at it until I find what I am doing wrong, or is there a better way?

Comment: I am a bit rusty on haskell but aren't you inferring the same type? (i mean aren't you forcing b and c to be from the same type?)

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. But the output is not quite correct. I will edit the question!

Comment: Don't do this, that edit would have changed the topic of the question. You may ask a new question, but please try first if you can figure out the new problem yourself.

Answer (score 7):

The subexpression `xs == ys` forces `xs` and `ys` to have the same type.

```
(==) :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

Calling this on your two lists forces `[(a,b)] = [(a,c)]`, hence `b = c`.  But you've declared in the type that you have two independent type variables, so unifying these is not allowed.

It looks to me like you should be comparing the actual first elements you got, rather than the lists as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

According to your example, I believe what you want `ljoin` to to is this:

```
for each element (xa, xb) of xs
  if there are elements in ys that xa == ya, then
    for each of these element (ya, yb) generates a (xa, xb, Just yb)
  else
    generates a (xa, xb, Nothing)
```

This could be translated to Haskell code directly:

```
ljoin xs ys = concatMap join xs
  where join (xa, xb) = case filter (\(ya, yb) -> xa == ya) ys of
                         [] -> [(xa, xb, Nothing)]
                         ys' -> map (\(_, yb) -> (xa, xb, Just yb)) ys'
```